# how to inserting and update image Summernote in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, summernote

I use summernote as a WYSIWYG on my web, but I get a problem that I can't find in google(not solve my problem), which is how to input images in my text-area using summernote and display them in view I have used various methods as below but still produce errors, I hope I can get the answer in this amazing StackOverflow.

I tried this code first :

```
$detail=$request->input('konten');
      $dom = new \DomDocument();
      libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
      $dom->loadHtml($detail, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
      $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
      foreach($images as $k => $img){

          $data = $img->getAttribute('src');
          list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
          list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
          $data = base64_decode($data);
          $image_name= "/img/blog" . time().$k. '.png';
          $path = public_path() . $image_name;
          file_put_contents($path, $data);
          $img->removeAttribute('src');
          $img->setAttribute('src', $image_name);
      }
      $detail = $dom->saveHTML();
```

and I save it to database, this work no error overall but the problem is, in my laravel directory the "laravel-5" environment not a default, I make folder name "main" for the "laravel" and that folder "main" become one directory in public, the problem is, $path = "public_path(). $image_name" not upload to the right directory on the public name "img/blog" but make a new directory on the MAIN folder, so when I show on the view that image did not show up because wrong directory the result on img src is img/blog/namefile.png, that must be https://somedomain.com/img/blog/namefile.png to show the image.

and I tried some library name `Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic`
and this the code :

```
$detail=$request->input('konten');
      $dom = new \DomDocument();
      $dom->loadHtml( mb_convert_encoding($detail, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
      $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach($images as $img){
            $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
            if(preg_match('/data:image/', $src)){
                // get the mimetype
                preg_match('/data:image\/(?<mime>.*?)\;/', $src, $groups);
                $mimetype = $groups['mime'];

                $filename = uniqid();
                $filepath = "/img/blog/$filename.$mimetype"; 

                $image = Image::make($src)
                  ->encode($mimetype, 50)  
                  ->save($filepath);

                $new_src = asset($filepath);
                $img->removeAttribute('src');
                $img->setAttribute('src', $new_src);
            }
        }
      $detail = $dom->saveHTML();
```

but the result is the image can't write to the directory, I don't know why, I tried the first one delete the public_path() and change to the URL, and have the same error.

```
//first trial

$detail=$request->input('konten');
      $dom = new \DomDocument();
      libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
      $dom->loadHtml($detail, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
      $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
      foreach($images as $k => $img){

          $data = $img->getAttribute('src');
          list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
          list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
          $data = base64_decode($data);
          $image_name= "/img/blog" . time().$k. '.png';
          $path = public_path() . $image_name;
          file_put_contents($path, $data);
          $img->removeAttribute('src');
          $img->setAttribute('src', $image_name);
      }
      $detail = $dom->saveHTML();

//second trial

$detail=$request->input('konten');
      $dom = new \DomDocument();
      $dom->loadHtml( mb_convert_encoding($detail, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
      $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach($images as $img){
            $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
            if(preg_match('/data:image/', $src)){
                // get the mimetype
                preg_match('/data:image\/(?<mime>.*?)\;/', $src, $groups);
                $mimetype = $groups['mime'];

                $filename = uniqid();
                $filepath = "/img/blog/$filename.$mimetype"; 

                $image = Image::make($src)
                  ->encode($mimetype, 50)  
                  ->save($filepath);

                $new_src = asset($filepath);
                $img->removeAttribute('src');
                $img->setAttribute('src', $new_src);
            }
        }
      $detail = $dom->saveHTML();
```

I expect the image uploaded to the right directory and can be shown on the view

Answer (score 1):

I am handling this problem with jquery/ajax couple, see my codes below :

Script (Don't forget changing #summernote id for your 'textarea' name):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#summernote').summernote({
                callbacks: {
                    onImageUpload: function(files) {
                        for(let i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
                            $.upload(files[i]);
                        }
                        console.log('file loading');
                    }
                },
                height: 200,
            });

            $.upload = function (file) {
                let out = new FormData();
                out.append('file', file, file.name);
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/admin/summernote_upload',
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: out,
                    success: function (img) {
                        $('#summernote').summernote('insertImage', img);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.error(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            };
        });


    </script>
```

Router: (I am using this router in admin group and prefix you can modify it on Ajax calling if you want)

```
#Summernote
Route::post('summernote_upload',['uses'=>'SummerNoteController@upload_image'])->name('summernote_upload_image');
```

NOTE: Don't forget to add meta to head tag for CSRF protection

Just add this line to after  tag

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

SummerNoteController :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SummerNoteController extends Controller
{
   public function upload_image(Request $request)
   {
       //make validation

       $image = $request->file('file')->store('public/uploads/editor');

       //in this blok you can change the logic.
       //you want I am using default laravel file handling

       return Storage::url($image);
   }
}
```

Comment: i don't know why but this not work for me, may be because i bad on javascript, so i don't understand the logic sorry but, i already tested it

Comment: What is wrong with it?. If you have any type of error share them with us. Additional to my answer I would like to emphasize that you need to run "php artisan storage:link" command for accessibly public storage.You can search any javascript error on console.